# OpenGL Translate Rotate Scale Transformation

Tags: opengl, rotation, translation, transformation

I am trying to create user firendly transformation class (Unity as example) that only holds (or only visible to user) position, rotation and translation vectors.

Applying the transformation is easy for OpenGL by using glTranslate, glRotate and glScale functions. I am calling Transform method for each object before it is about to be drawn. But I am having a trouble with changing position related by a rotation. Here is my code.

// A sample Rendering method for an object

```
    void Render()
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        transform->Transform();

        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_colors->constData());
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_positions->constData());
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6);

        glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

// Transformation class

```
    class Transformation
    {

    public:

        QVector3D Position;
        QVector3D Rotation;
        QVector3D Scale;

        Transformation()
        {
            Position = QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Rotation = QVector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            Scale    = QVector3D(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        ~Transformation()
        {

        }

        void Translate(const QVector3D& amount)
        {

        }

        void Rotate(const QVector3D& amount)
        {
            Rotation += amount;

            Rotation.setX(AdjustDegree(Rotation.x()));
            Rotation.setY(AdjustDegree(Rotation.y()));
            Rotation.setZ(AdjustDegree(Rotation.z()));
        }

        void Transform()
        {
            // Rotation
            glRotatef(Rotation.x(), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glRotatef(Rotation.y(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glRotatef(Rotation.z(), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            // Translation
            glTranslatef(Position.x(), Position.y(), Position.z());

            // Scale
            glScalef(Scale.x(), Scale.y(), Scale.z());
        }

    };
```

How can I Translate?

Comment: My advice: Don't use OpenGL builtin transformation matrix manipulators. For one they're cumbersome to work with. And more importantly, they've been completely scraped from later versions. Use a real matrix math library like GLM, Eigen or linmath.h

Comment: Thanks for the tips but none of them is answering to my question. I am asking how to translate by rotation degrees.

Comment: That's why I wrote this as a _comment_.

Answer (score 3):

The transformations in openGL are stored in a stack and then, they are apply to the model inversely. In your code, you apply first the scale, then the translate and lastly the rotate. Since the rotate is made from (0, 0, 0), if you have moved (translate) the object, you will change its position. To rotate an object, its center should be in (0, 0, 0).

The correct order of transformations is: Scale/Rotate and then Translate

So, in your code, the translation should be the first transformation you make.

Comment: Good tip I didn't use scale yet. I only know rotation must be applied before translation. Thanks.

Comment: @CahitBurakKüçüksütcü But note that the transformations are stored in a stack, so the are applied inversely. You have to apply rotation first, so you have to code rotation the lastest

Comment: @Stratford: Actually OpenGL transformations are *not* stored in a stack. The matrix stack serves a wholly different purpose, namely to be able to create a reversable hierachy of transformations. But when you call OpenGL transformation functions in succession they only in place multiply on one single 4×4 matrix.

Comment: @datenwolf I know, but I used the word _store_ to do it more understandable to him :)